# How to change background color of checkbox when checkbox is IsChecked in XAML in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, checkbox, windows-phone-8.1

Is there any way to change check box background color in xaml not c# . I know there are `Checked` and `UnChecked` event .but I have to use in Xaml . 
I have refer its template but can't find the solution . please help me for that

Thank you

Comment: This is pretty simple. If you have the style template and want to post it, it's literally just adding a `ColorAnimation` to an existing object in the template, or adding another and toggling its visibility in the `Checked` state in the `VisualStateManager`

Comment: I have refer it's edit template , I have not any custom template . If you have please post here .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the edit template style of the checkbox lookout for the x:Name="Checked" visualstate.

Add the following animation inside the storyboard to change the background of the checkbox when checked:

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background"
                               Storyboard.TargetName="Grid">
      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                              Value="#FFABCDEF" />  // argb value of your desired background color
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Comment: Its works when "Storyboard.TargetName="CheckBackground"

Comment: i thought you wanted to change the background for entire check-box so i suggested "Grid". "CheckBackground" wont change the background for check-box content it will only change for the check mark only.

Comment: Okay ! , that's why I accept the answer . keep coding Thank you !