# Re-usable DataGridTemplateColumn Style

Tags: wpf, xaml, checkbox, styles, datagridtemplatecolumn

I would like to have a datagrid with a checkbox column with the following behavior: The checkbox is centered in the cell and the cell background is green when the checkbox is checked.

Presently I achieve this with a style for a DataGridTemplateColumn (see below). This style works fine, however the propertyname to which the checkbox is bound is referenced twice within the style.
So I cannot apply the style to another column/grid which is bound to another object/property.

Is there a way to create a re-usable solution (either with DataGridCheckBoxColumn or otherwise) where the bound property can be passed into?

My present xaml style:

```
<Style x:Key="IsClipToCalendarCheckBoxCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsClipToCalendar, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsClipToCalendar}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="DeepSkyBlue" />
       </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create `DataTemplates` dynamically in code-behind of your `Window`:

```
private string StringTemplate =
   @"<DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content=""fooTemplate"" />
            <TextBox Text=""{Binding Path=fooColumn}""/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>";
```

and in  `AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn"` you can use your `DataTemplate`:

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    DataTemplate dt = null;
    string dtString = StringTemplate.Replace("fooColumn", e.PropertyName);
    dt = GetDataTemplateForDataGrid(dtString);
    DataGridTemplateColumn c = new DataGridTemplateColumn()
    {
       CellTemplate = dt,
       Header = e.Column.Header,
       HeaderTemplate = e.Column.HeaderTemplate,
       HeaderStringFormat = e.Column.HeaderStringFormat,
       SortMemberPath = e.PropertyName
    };
    e.Column = c;
 }
```

and method to get `DateTemplates`:

```
private DataTemplate GetDataTemplateForDataGrid(string templateString)
    {
        ParserContext context = new ParserContext();
        context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation");
        context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");
        return (DataTemplate)Parse(templateString, context);
    }
```

and method to parse non-English letters, if you use binding with non-English letters:

```
    public static object Parse(string xamlText, ParserContext parserContext)
    {
        return System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load((Stream)new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xamlText)), parserContext);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try making changes in the Checked Visual state of the checkbox instead of having a trigger. I have answered it for windows phone 8.1 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35221472/how-to-change-background-color-of-checkbox-when-checkbox-is-ischecked-in-xaml-in/35405815#35405815). Adapt it for wpf accordingly.

Hope it helps! :)